# Blazor Layout with CascadingParameter initialized after component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Is there any way to force a Blazor Layout to be initialized before its component? I find it's not always consistent, depending on how/when the page is accessed. It causes issues when I've defined a CascadingParameter in the Layout which the component depends on.

Component setup:

```
@page "/parent1/parent2/parent3/things/1/details"
@layout MyLayout

// show thing here

@code
{
    [CascadingParameter] public object Thing { get; set; } // can be null

    protected override void OnInitialized() 
    {
        // this may occur before or after the layout is initialized

        // do something with Thing
    }
}
```

Layout setup:

```
@inherits LayoutBase

@if (thing is not null) {
    <CascadingValue Value="@thing" IsFixed="true">
        @Body
    </CascadingValue>
}

@code {
    object thing;

    protected override void OnInitialized() 
    {
       // this may occur before or after the component is initialized
       thing = GetThingFromDatabase();

       // validate thing here
    }
}
```

I thought Layouts would be the best place to guard/validate/authorize the route parameters and then store objects for any child pages but if the timing is random that doesn't work. For example, I'm after a page structure like the following.

```
/things/1  (layout/abstract page)
   /things/1/details  (page using layout)
   /things/1/otherStuff  (page using layout)
   /things/1/moreStuff  (page using layout)
```

I only want to load the thing once and keep it around as they navigate between the child pages.

Comment: `App.razor` sets up your router to use MainLayout. More specifically `RouteView` does.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to force a Blazor Layout to be initialized before its component?

You, the programmer, have no control over component instantiation.  That's all handled by the Renderer.

> I only want to load the thing once and keep it around as they navigate between the child pages?

Use a Scoped Service that gets and holds thing - ThingService - and inject it into whatever component needs it.

Here's some example code:

First the service.  Register as Scoped Service.

```cs
namespace StackOverflow.Server
{
    public class Thing
    {
        public string? ThisThing { get; set; }
        public bool Loading => this.ThisThing is null;

        public async Task GetThing()
        {
            // Emulated a real async database operation
            await Task.Delay(500);
            this.ThisThing = "Successful Database get";
        }
    }
}
```

A component to demo the cascade.

```
<h3>ShowThing Component</h3>
<div class="m-3">
Thing: @thing!.ThisThing
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private Thing? thing { get; set; }
}
```

A test page:

```
@page "/"
<CascadingValue Value=Thing>
    <ShowThing />
</CascadingValue>

<div class="m-3">
Thing: @this.Thing.ThisThing
</div>

@code {
    [Inject] Thing? Thing { get; set; }

    protected async  override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Thing!.GetThing();
    }
}
```

Notice that you don't need to test if `thing` is not `null`.  I've removed the `IsFixed`, you don't need it.  The cascade handles nulls.  When `Thing` gets a real value in `OnInitializedAsync`, the post `OnInitializedAsync` render event detects the change in `Thing` and passes the changes on to any components registered for the cascade by calling `SetParametersAsync` on those components, triggering a component render.

Comment: In this setup I have noticed that the nested component initializes twice due to the if statement in the layout, but only if the component initializes before the layout. If the component loads first the cascading parameter will be null. After the layout loads it won't be. On component initialization I decided to just check if the cascading parameter is null right away and break if it is, then just wait for the component to initialize a 2nd time (soon after the layout is initialized). The page looks fine but I'm guessing this is not a good workflow with Blazor.

Comment: Correct.  See my updated answer.   I run it in a test page, but you can implement it in your layout.  Note the comments about not needing to check `thing` when you set up the cascading parameter.   You should always use services to hold, get and manage your data.  Keep all that out of the UI.  It's really, REALLY important to get your head around the Component life cycle and rendering.  It saves shooting yourself in the foot multiple times!